# Jess defquery and accumulate CE

Tags: rule-engine, jess, accumulate

I am new to Jess The Rule Engine and I am having a trouble with a simple query.
I have a simple java bean file and a .clp file . By using java bean file I create word objects and by using .clp I do some processes, by defining rules, on imported java objects which are now in the working memory of Jess. And at the end of the rules that I described I want to perform a query which will find the highest sentenceNumber - sentenceNumber is a slot variable in my Word fact- by using the accumulate conditional element. And also I want to return the resulting value to Java code. The problem is that the query that I wrote gives me error if I do use accumulate CE in the query but not in the defrule.

So my question is : Is it inappropriate to use accumulate CE in a query? 
I could not find any material which says yes or no.

Below I give you my query :

```
(defquery get-Total-Sentence-Number
 "this query gets the total number of newly created sentences"
 ;(accumulate <initializer> <action> <result> <conditional element>)
 ?result <- (accumulate (bind ?max FALSE) ;initializer
                        (if (or (not ?max);action
                        (> ?sentenceNumber ?max))
                             then (bind ?max ?sentenceNumber))
                        ?max ;result
                        (Word (sentenceNumber ?sentenceNumber))))
```

Please help.
Thank you

p.s. I do not want to use the accumulate CE in a defrule because as I understood a rule will fire itself again and again in every change of the fact list. And I just want to perform this only once which I need it at the end of the rules that I defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a restriction. Anyway, it doesn't really make sense to run an accumulate in a query. It would be easier to define a query returning the facts:

```
(defquery get-words
   (Word (sentenceNumber ?sentenceNumber)))
```

to run it, and to evaluate the maximum in an iteration over the queried collection:

```
(bind ?result (run-query* get-words))

(bind ?max 0)
(while (?result next) do
    (bind ?snr (?result getString sentenceNumber))
    (if (> ?snr ?max) then (bind ?max ?snr))
)
(printout t "max: " ?max crlf)
```

**Later**
Then I recommend the following approach:

```
;; define an auxiliary fact
(deftemplate MaxWord (slot maxSentence))

;; initialze one fact
(deffacts  maximum
  (MaxWord (maxSentence 0))
)

;; a rule to compute the maximum
(defrule setMax
  ?mw <- (MaxWord (maxSentence ?ms))
  (Word (sentenceNumber ?snr & :(> ?snr ?ms)))
=>
  (modify ?mw (maxSentence ?snr))
)

 ;; the query
(defquery getMax
   (MaxWord (maxSentence ?maxSentence)))

;; obtain the result
(bind ?result (run-query* getMax))
(?result next)
(bind ?max (?result getString maxSentence))
(printout t "max: " ?max crlf)
```

Note that this does not work correclty if Word facts are retracted, which is bound to invalidate the maximum.

An entirely different approach can be made by using a rule with accumulate and an initial (auxiliary) fact that needs to be asserted when the rule should fire. This would avoid the frequent repetition of accumulate. Basically:

```
(defrule "calcMax"
  (FreeToCalc)
  ?result <- (accumulate (bind ?max 0)
                    (if  (> ?sentenceNumber ?max)
                         then (bind ?max ?sentenceNumber))
                    ?max
              (Word (sentenceNumber ?sentenceNumber))))
 =>
 ;;...
 )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your response. But I want to return the query result to Java code - my mistake I did not specify it in the description, sorry. And by using the code that you wrote I need to implement the second part of your code in Java which I do not want it. I want to do everything in Jess and return only the final result to Java as an integer value.

Comment: Hello again and thank you for your suggestions. I combined your 2nd solution with salience and also returned the value of the maxSentence slot to Java - which is quite complex I think.